# Multiple divs in online first and force the next pair down to the next line depending on the size of the screen?

Tags: html, css

Multiple `div`s, each with a label and a dropdown. What is the simplest way to force the dropdown/label pair to always be on the same line, and force the next pair down to the next line depending on the size of the screen?

So far I have:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; width:100%;">
    <div style="float:left; width:40%; display:block;">
        <label for="zone"><b><%=zonestr%></b></label> 
        <select id="zone" name="zone" onchange="getDIV();start();">
            <option value=""><%=selectstr%><%=zonestr%></option>
            <option value="1">value1</option>
            <option value="2">value2</option>
            <option value="3">value3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:60%;">
        <label for="district"> <b><%=resultstr%></b> </label>
        <select id="district" name="district">
            <option value=""><%=selectstr%><%=resultstr%></option>
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap grid as per codepen link have:
codepen.io/greatzspido/pen/YrvQry

If you don't want to include complete bootstrap, you can use ultimate light weight grid structure of https://neat.bourbon.io/.

Comment: can I only use css? I am maintain a old project

Comment: Yes you can use compile CSS.